# Pandas convert some columns data to rows

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I checked almost all topics on stackoverflow related to convert columns to rows, but didn't find solution for my problem,

**so my dataframe looks like this:**

```
Year  Week Product sessions conversion
19Y  01W    P01      30        10%
19Y  02W    P01      20        12%
19Y  01W    P02      40        15%
19Y  02W    P02      50        18%
20Y  01W    P01      15        12%
20Y  02W    P01      25        15%
20Y  01W    P02      35        16%
20Y  02W    P02      45        17%
```

**My desired output is:**

```
   product             19Y01W 20Y01W 19Y02W 20Y02W
    P01    session      30     15      20     25
           conversion   10%    12%     12%    15%
    P02    session      40     35      50     35
           conversion   15%    16%     18%    17%
```

I tried to do it with pivot_table, groubpy, or unstack, but didn't succeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `unstack` and `stack`:

```
df['YW'] = df['Year']+df['Week']
df.drop(['Year','Week'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df1 = df.set_index(['Product','YW']).unstack(level=1).stack(level=0)
df1.loc[:, sorted(df1.columns.to_list(), key= lambda x: x[2:])]
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, the only problem with "yearweeks" sequence, it became like 19Y01W, 19Y02W, 20Y01W, 20Y02W. It there is any way to make it like: 19Y01W, 20Y01W, 19Y02W, 20Y02W?

Comment: @Antonych Check the update and accept if it worked for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. It works perfectly, the more important thing is now i can understand how stack and unstack works.